# Что означает

Tags: значение-слов

В Брянске я часто слышу выражение "что зря",в значении "плохой", например, погода "что зря",платье купила "что зря" и т.д. Также говорят "глумной" о человеке, в смысле "туповатый".Говорят ли так ещё где-нибудь или это брянские "придумки."?

Comment: Столетней давности цитата :  
>И.Е. Вольнов (И.Е. Владимиров). Повесть о днях моей жизни (1912) Бает: нечего орясничать, работать надо, ну, и гнись, козёл глумной, потей, смеши деревню! ..
 .. Я же говорил тебе: как глумной, волосья на себе дерет!

Интересные акценты) Типа "ну сумасшедший, что возьмешь..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глумной - явно диалект, и в разных областях привносят свои оттенки:
http://www.slova.ru/article/5757.html

А вот "что зря" -не слышала, только "почём зря" = безрассудно быстро, может, и диалект, а может, просто просторечие. Что зря = как зря, зря - без пользы, вполне подходит по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

Глумной - от "глумиться". Соответственно и все значения крутятся вокруг "тот, над кем глумятся". У меня это слово в "пассивном запасе", т.е. слышал не один раз, какого-то ареала употребления не отмечал.