# Как можно объяснить значение фразеологизма «почем зря»?

Tags: значение-слов, фразеология

**Значение** словосочетания «почем зря» понятно, и оно часто используется в речи.

Но почему оно приобрело такое **значение**, какова его **история**?

Спасибо.

P. S. Как оказалось, **не очень-то и  понятно...**

Comment: может почём - зря это своего рода сокращенные вопрос и ответ.  "и стал стрелять почем зря" - почему(почём) стал стрелять?.. а, ясно, ну зря он стал стрелять. То есть рассказ о чем-то не требуется, так как всё равно дело - зря, бесполезное, не нужное. То есть такой способ пропустить обстоятельства: почём(у)? - зря.

Comment: "Мы мечемся по сцене почем зря, и как-то ничего не выходит." Почему мы мечемся по сцене? зря мы это делаем. - мечемся почём-зря. То есть сразу и вопрос, и ответ.  "Почем знать, что вы хотите." - почём - это изначально вопрос сходный с почему, а уже позже стал вопросом о цене чего-то.

Comment: У него же значение по словарю "очень сильно" https://rus-phraseology-dict.slovaronline.com/10313-Почём%20зря

Comment: я видел, но не ясно откуда такое вообще значение. Мне кажется почём зря - это скорее такое действие, которое не получается завершить. Просто ввиду специфики неразумного поведения, это может быть связано с излишним деструктивном, актор не в состоянии ответить зачем он  делает заведомо "зря".  "Для поляка все ясно ― скотина безответная, пали почем зря ― режь, насилуй, истязай" Бабель, тут нет значения очень сильно, однако тщетность деструктивных усилий - таки да.

Comment: "― Я вообще могу сказать, что с Гвоздевым загадка вышла. Пропадает почем зря." Здесь значение скорее "совсем", совсем пропадает, с концами. А не "очень сильно". "Очень сильно", может в каком-то предложении отдельном. И тут почём зря может быть связано с поиском, мы его ищем, а он пропадает, наши усилия тщетны.

Comment: То есть почём зря - это указание на тщетность усилий говорящего в связи с ситуацией, что бы не делал говорящий, не получается исправить ситуацию, как-то так.

Comment: Вот и мне это значение не совсем понятно... Мне кажется, что его в разных ситуациях можно применить и с разным значением (у кого какое).

Comment: "Уже проехав квартал, он не без боязни оглянулся: ― Плюется и костерит почем зря!.. Ишь ты, вражина…" Шолохов. То есть герой сбежав от кого-то, начинает оценивать чье-то поведение, и почём зря тут, скорее указание, что "что бы я не делал, он все равно плюется и костерит" = "все мои усилия зря, не его усилия, а мои(героя)". Я бы отнес это к внутренней речи говорящего, а не чему-то фактическому. Сам себе задал вопрос, сам ответил на него. Как-то так.

Comment: "Дерется почем зря и всегда в синяках ходит." - я знаю, что он дерется и ходит в синяках, говорю ему, но всё зря, - какая-то такая история. А на счет словаря - не знаю, какой-то новый словарь, кто его составлял? какие-то халтурщики? Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008. Такие значения не проходят и  минимальную проверку ведь...

Comment: "Иного за дело, за пьянствие, и почем зря сажают." - вот это еще, вообще не подходит к "сильно, вовсю" как можно посадить кого-то вовсю)? Ну с другой стороны, в 2008 не было Нацкорпуса, чтобы проверить значения.

Comment: Нужна, наверное, новая идея при толковании...

Comment: Хотя некоторые можно трактовать "сильно, вовсю," казалось бы: «Здорово их девки-то испужали! Свету не видят, гонят почем зря!» Бажов. Но вот опять Бажов и:
Он, видишь, сперва, для устрашенья видно, две пулеметных ленты израсходовал почем зря, ― по таежному лесу."

Как можно израсходовать патроны "вовсю"? Явно, что он использует этот оборот иначе.

Comment: У меня после обсуждения появилась смутная идея, но я не очень в ней уверена. Надо подождать другие ответы или комментарии.

Comment: Хорошо, ну я попозже оформлю в ответ тогда, не буду торопиться и торопить), но в целом я изложил моё видение в комментариях.

Answer (score 4):

Не помню, приходилось ли мне использовать это выражение... А когда оно встречается, в голове у меня смысл такой: ***напрасно, бездумно, зря, цена не стоила того***. И уже не важно, **как** что-то происходило или происходит – ***много, сильно, без разбору, просто так***. Важно то, что **говорящий отрицательно оценивает действие**. И составляющие ***почём зря*** сами об этом говорят. Вот [здесь](https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=12454), например, такой "диалог":

> — Знакомый бразилец, изучающий русский язык, попросил меня объяснить
> слово «почём». Я сказал, что это то же самое, что и «сколько стоит?»
> На следующий день у него возник следующий вопрос: Значит – выражение
> «почём зря» означает «сколько стоит зря?» Нет, не значит. Но почему
> так… я застопорился ответить.
>
> — Отчасти значит. Только здесь нет вопроса, а *зря* в данном выражении — не «товар», а оценка ожидаемой пользы. А затраты, «цена» — некие усилия, потраченные зря, т. е. без пользы. Собственно говоря, никакого практического результата прикладывавший усилия и не ожидал, имело место просто самовыражение и выпускание пара, и на это указывает слово *почём*: деятель знает, что практический результат будет нулевой, *зряшный*, и сознательно идёт на зряшные затраты. Когда-то слово *зря* в современном смысле было не в ходу (оно было в ходу в другом смысле), а в нынешнем смысле тогда говорили и писали — *даром*.

Почему-то значение ***напрасно*** мне не попалось пока, хотя оно первое, что приходит в голову.

Answer (score 2):

Есть в ответе Людмилы от 2013 г. кое-что справочное — "почём зря" = безрассудно быстро ([Что означает](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27226/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/27229#27229)), и есть росссыпь живых цитат с «почём зря» в НКРЯ, из которых можно дать малую долю из многих значений этого словосочетания: *ни на что не взирая; не разбираясь; без разбору; просто, просто так; от небольшого ума; от балды; от нечего делать; куражась*.

Comment: Спасибо, я посмотрела ответ, но "безрассудно быстро" вряд ли подходит. А применение фразеологизма в Нацорпуссе  весьма разнообразно...  Думаю, что пользователи часто используют свою трактовку сочетания.  А в каких фразах вы его применяете, если вообще применяете?

Comment: Если говорю, то в значении «без разбору» или «сорви голову». Но всё, что в НК понятно и близко. Только фразеологизмом не называл бы, хотя признак есть (сумма слов не есть сумма смыслов), потому что, наверное, очень велик выбор синонимов.

Answer (score 2):

**Комментарий к ответам**

**Спасибо всем**, кто ответил, им я с удовольствием ставлю «лайки», но это  всего лишь десять баллов. Я бы с бОльшим удовольствием выписала бы им премию. Сколько?  Ну, сто баллов как минимум))

Прочитав ответы, в том числе Александра, я подумала:  ***как удивителен русский язык, сколько в нем загадок!*** Даже носители языка слышат его по-разному, так что тогда говорить об изучающих наш язык.

Прочитав ответ Буратино, я  стала думать о том, как **много в нем непознанного, таинственного, глубинного.**  (Очень интересен разбор слова "***почем***.")

Но язык меняется, и многие нераскрытые тайны уходят еще дальше от нас. Поэтому важно **записать** хотя бы эту страницу: как наши современники слышат и понимают его.

Я обратила внимание на "***почем зря***" недавно, когда использовала его в примерно такой фразе:  *Буду я еще **почем зря** стараться, если это никому не надо.*  Немного похоже **на междометие**: экспрессия, выражение недовольства.

А вот сейчас я слышу как бы **дословный «перевод»** с деепричастным оборотом:  *Буду я еще, **почем зря**, стараться.* Или:  Буду я еще стараться (***видя цену своих усилий***), если это никому не надо.

И очень хотелось бы услышать **и другие ответы**  тоже...

Comment: я поправлю, не изменяется, а искажается. Искажение ведет к обессмысливанию слов и в итоге к разрушению языка, больше ни к чему. Когда из слова получается ругательство или сленг, который хочется вымарать. И касательно коммуникативного языка, вот видимо есть еще экспрессивный, когда эмоции и есть собственно речь, когда причина и следствие. Коммуникация - это только для, для того,что потом, язык системы, когда делаешь что-то, а почему не знаешь. Экспрессия - это вообще набот криков мартышек, когда не знаешь ни почему, ни для чего. А речь - это человеческий язык, связанный с разумом, размышлением.

Comment: Может, это смайлики? Я один убрала.

Answer (score 1):

***ЗрЯ, / поймешь, // что всё это напрасно…***

1. **Фразеологизм  этот удивительный**

Мы видим в нем два значения: (1) **очень сильно и затратно** и (2) **напрасно, безрезультатно** и используем в речи соответственно (то так то этак).

А иногда видим только одно значение: ***или сильно/затратно, или напрасно.***

2. Но вот **цельный смысл** фразеологизма – это скорее **идиома**, чем обычное сочетание слов.

**Как появилось слово «зря»?**  Наречие «зря» по происхождению связано с древнерусским глаголом «зьрѣти» (зреть, смотреть). Наречие образовано от деепричастия «зря» (смотря на что-то). Деепричастие встречаем у Державина «Не зря, тебе того нельзя вообразить,/ Я, видев, разве тень могу лишь изразить».
[О наречии "зря"](https://dzen.ru/a/XoSXi71uiEwhF6aE)

3. Поэтому **значение фразеологизма** можно описать так: если посмотришь внимательно (***зря***), то увидишь, что так делать не стоит.

Или так: *– И **почём** всё это? – **Дорого уж очень уж, а результатов не видно.***

Или совсем коротко: ***почём, зря*** (видя).

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**[Фразеологический словарь](https://rus-phraseology-dict.slovaronline.com/10313-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F):** Прост. Экспрес. **Сильно, вовсю** (бить, ругать и т. п.). Мамонец оказался очень старательным «полицаем». Всё время вертелся на глазах начальства, ругал партизан почём зря (Д. Медведев. Это было под Ровно).
Синонимы: во всю ивановскую, вовсю, и в хвост и в гриву, очень сильно, сильно.

**Примеры**

***Напрасно***

*Удача – девица ветреная, любит только умных и расчётливых, тех, кто не рискует **почём зря.***
Возможно, этому мешал животный страх, нежелание сигать в неведомое и пропадать там **почём зря.**
*Разве стал бы **почём зря** беспокоить?*
*Не тратя время **почём зря**, так как понятия не имею, что делать с реликвией, наделённой такой старой магией, решила заглянуть в мамин гримуар.*

***Сильно***

*Я клял себя **почем зря**, твердил, что достоин самого тяжкого наказания.*
*Вася (старый автомобиль) угрюмо выкидывал коленца ― шерудел дворниками и буксовал **почем зря**.*
*Нет, с виду-то всё понятно – оздоравливают люди друг дружку **почём зря** кулаками и ногами.*

***Много и без дела***

*Хороший он парень и языком не мелет **почем зря**.*

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется проблема в слове почём, которое ассоциируется с ценой, "в какую цену", так как "почём продаешь". Хотя это скорее всего один из случаев употребления слова почем/почём.

Однако, изначально, почем - это одна из версий почему, содержащая целый комплекс вариаций - "отчего", "откуда", "по что", "отколь" то есть вопрос совсем не о цене, а причинно-следственный.

> ― А почем я знаю… говорят, что мачкин сын… Лермонтов.

Тут почем я знаю ~ откуда мне знать.

> ― Если б я влюбился, то, может быть, стал бы писать… Знаешь, что пришло мне в голову? ― Я должен благодарить бога, что не люблю. Почем знать? Может быть, судьба ведет меня, как говорит Марья Афанасьевна! 13. Н. В. Станкевич. Письма Я. М. Неверову (1833)

Сейчас скажут ~ "как узнаешь?".

> ― Хлестаков. А соуса почем нет? Слуга. Гоголь.

А соуса "отчего" нет?

То есть есть так же в обращении фраза "почем знать", а противоположная ей версия будет "почем зря", то есть вопрос не требующий ответа.

― Почем знать, он его лупит?

― Он его лупит почем зря!

То есть совсем зря, и я соглашусь с "напрасно". Однако, ввиду того, что почем, это именно вопрос, то это не коммуникативная речь, то есть не внешняя, а внутренняя, кусок внутреннего монолога в речи. Наоборот, отказ рассказывать или делиться обстоятельствами дела, так как зря. Лупит, но об этом рассказывать нет смыла.

Ах да, еще стоит сказать о зря. Зря это от зрение, зрить, то есть видеть. Зря это "видя", "наблюдая" или "полагаясь на", "ожидая с основанием".

> Рукомесленникъ обливается потомъ, зря достойную за труды свои плату.

> И мудрость, как почтить тебя, сама не знает, / Зря, что безумие твой разум похваляет.

То есть зря - это зрение, но разума, а не прихоти.

Так что тут получатся что почем зря. Это когда внутренний голос, голос разума произносит: "смотри, что ты делаешь, ты же видишь, что творишь?". Почем зря используется для подчеркивания очевидности какого-то неразумного действия или события.

Но тут нужно понять одну хитрую вещь, разум, это не Я, а Ты. В этом смысле, фразы голоса разума универсальны, это комплекс вопросов к самому себе: "Почему ты так поступаешь, ты же видишь?" Его может задавать как говорящий, так и тот кому говорят, так и тот о ком идет речь - вопрос всегда будет один, и он внутренний, а не внешний. Внешне человек может врать, выдумывать версии, для чего он делает то или другое и врать выдумывая прочую казуистику. Но ведь внутренний голос не обманешь.

Казуистика, кстати говоря, от case/causal... Почему я беру сразу два слова, потому что "[The terms case and cause are synonyms (words with similar meaning)](https://www.classicthesaurus.com/case/and/cause#:%7E:text=The%20terms%20case%20and%20cause%20are%20synonyms%20(words%20with%20similar%20meaning).)(**!?**)" - вот что пишут про них в современном английском, или вот:

> *cause - [countable] a case that goes to court,*
>
> *case - [countable] a question to be decided in court -*

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338576/cause-vs-case-in-law), то есть даже сам-весь Британский словарь ляпает применительно к судебной лексике, что обстоятельство/событие/случай/факт и причина это одно и тоже в некотором контексте. Каким образом это происходит, я в замешательстве. Ну не говоря уже о том, что у нас причинно-следственная связь, а у них причинная. Ну это к тому, к чему ведет голая семантика, когда слово - не связано с основой, а связано с ошибочным референсом.

Поэтому, я предлагаю четко разделять вопросы(прежде всего) почём, почему и сколько. Почем продаешь? - это "почему ты продаешь", а не сколько это стоит. Вот в чем соль. Причина определяет продажи определяет цену, а не денежный эквивалент. Почем купил? - это " что ты отдал, за то что взял", можно употреблять и при бартере, купил лошадь за 10 мешков картошки.

Рассказом про внутреннюю речь в русском не буду перегружать и без того сложноватый текс, в другой раз.

Резюмируя:

Почём зря ~ напрасно.

Однако, этимологически - это кусок внутренней речи в тексте, похожий на риторический вопрос "отчего делаешь очевидное плохое?", употребляемый в случае необдуманного/неразумного поведения кого-то. Суть в том, что почём зря - это не оценка "бездумно", но предложение оценить обстоятельства дела слушателю.

Ругается "почём зря" - Видишь, ругается, почему - не знаю, но ругается очевидно.

Употребления же почём зря в подобным образом излишне:

> Он всех этих фигурантов по дурости «мочил» почем зря, без разбору.

Тут очевидно *почем зря* употреблено зря, так как уже есть "по дурости", то есть тут "почем зря" и/или "без разбору"(лучше вообще что-то одно из трех). Ну да ладно, не стоит учиться на плохих примерах.